# How to enable a button based on click even

Tags: html, vbscript

Can anybody help me how to enable a button based on a click event.

I need a scenario, where we have 2 buttons, Button1 and Button2(disabled by default).

Upon clicking on Button1, say after 10 seconds my Button2 should be enabled.

Where i am doing wrong in the below code? My Button2 is not enabled after i click on Button1. Can anybody help me.

Thanks in advance,
Uday

```
<html>
<Head>
<Title>Synchronization</Title>
</head>
<script>
function PleaseWait()
{
    document.getElementsByName("SampleButton2").disabled=false;
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="button" name="SampleButton1" value="Button1" onclick="PleaseWait()">
<input type="button" name="SampleButton2" value="Button2" disabled>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery.

Inside $(document).ready() method, define a function PleaseWait(), where you can write the code to remove disabled attribute form your button.

Then when any user clicks on button1, trigger a function to call pleaseWait() function after a delay using setTimeout() method. I used 5 milliseconds for delay. You can increase or decrease it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DOM Level 0 Events Example</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" name="SampleButton1" value="Button1">
<input type="button" name="SampleButton2" value="Button2" disabled>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e){

    function PleaseWait(){
        $('input[value="Button2"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

    $('input[value="Button1"]').click(function(e) {
        setTimeout(PleaseWait, 5000);
    });

  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can see your code is working fine for me, but i am novice in jQuery, can you please provide your inputs in HTML code? Can something in my code is corrected to make it work?

Comment: Hi, your HTML code is just fine. However in your javascript code, you have used getElementsByName method. In that case you should give the index of that element as well. Check your modified code below. Hope you will understand :-)

` 
<input type="button" name="SampleButton1" value="Button1" onclick="setTimeout(PleaseWait, 5000)">  
<input type="button" name="SampleButton2" value="Button2" disabled>  
<script>  
function PleaseWait()  
{  
 document.getElementsByName("SampleButton2")[0].disabled = false;  
}
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementsByName("SampleButton2").removeAttr('disabled');
```

or you can use

```
$('SampleButton2').prop('disabled', false);
```